# Firebase Remote Config/Realtime database on Huawei devices

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-services, firebase-remote-config, huawei-mobile-services

Are all of the Firebase services for Android unable to work on Huawei or is it just the cloud messaging service that does not work? Do all of the firebase services rely on Google Play Services?

Comment: All of the Google Play Services are unable to work on Huawei.

Comment: Google Play Services != Firebase

Comment: I haven't been able to get Firebase Remote Config to work on Huawei devices in our React Native app... I tried the web SDK route (which works for our Firebase Auth implementation), but the Remote Config library is not supported on Node JS and doesn't work. Sad panda

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Firebase SDKs** can be divided into **three** categories:

1. *Play services required* — These SDKs require Google Play services, otherwise they have no functionality.
2. *Play services recommended* — These SDKs require Google Play services to have full functionality, but they still offer most functionality even without Google Play services.
3. *Play services not required* — These SDKS do not require Google Play services to have full functionality.

[List of Firebase SDKs that don't require Google Play services](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services#google_play_services_not_required)

[List of Firebase SDKs that you need to include Google Play services](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services#google_play_services_required_or_recommended)

**Remote Config SDK** `com.google.firebase:firebase-config:20.0.0`  doesn't require Google Play Services.

**Realtime Database SDK** `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1`    doesn't require Google Play Services.
But keep in mind that Realtime Database depends on Firebase Auth (it needs an authenticated user to work) which depends on Google Play Services. For that you can use Firebase Auth REST API instead of Firebase Auth SDK.

For more info [Use Firebase Authentication without Google Play services](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services#auth-without-play-services)

---

**Update 27 Oct 2020:**

Firebase Auth SDK v20.0.0 `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.0` doesn't require Google Play Service.

Answer (score 8):

Official [Dependencies of Firebase Android SDKs on Google Play services](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services)

The following Firebase products depend on **Firebase Authentication**.

1. **Firebase Realtime Database**
2. **Cloud Firestore**
3. **Cloud Functions**
4. **Cloud Storage**

You just need to replace Firebase Authentication with [Firebase Auth REST SDK](https://jitpack.io/#anotherdev/firebase-auth-rest). Using this SDK, you don't need to change your existing Firebase Realtime Database code. It will start working on Huawei devices and also GMS devices as well.

Docs: [Firebase Auth REST SDK - How to use Firebase Authentication on HMS phones](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201236170057510086)

Comment: That's a very nice answer! How reliable is it though? I mean can we rely on that for example Firebase Realtime Db will always depend on Firebase Auth, without play services dependencies

Comment: That's very good question. I have these concerns as well when trying to develop this SDK. From research, I think 1. It was not intentional and they are trying to undo it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60742408/802421). 2. Strategically they shouldn't increase dependency to GMS because Huawei Cloud is available on both HMS and GMS devices.

Comment: You can view this SDK as an interim solution to get your existing apps working on Huawei devices quickly. Of course we are ready to support you, if you want to migrate to Huawei Cloud DB. :)

Answer (score 4):

Firebase official stance is that all Firebase services require Google Play Services to work. Yes, some Firebase services actually work without GPS currently, however this can change at any time without prior notice.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase services will not work on the new Huawei Phones.
For Huawei devices you can take a look to HMS and App Gallery Connect Services

**Remote config:** https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-remoteconfig-introduction

**Cloud DB:** https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/clouddb-apply

**Push Notifications:** https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/push-introduction

To make your app compatible with all devices, you can use the G+H solution:
https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201200435859940059&fid=0101187876626530001