# Will Firestore and Google SignIn work on Huawei AppGallery?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

This is the first time I'm uploading an app to the App Gallery and I've read about things like HMS and other related things there are to know however I'm still not sure about the two things I'm using in my app. I'm going to submit the app I've built to Huawei AppGallery. I have only used two things:

1. Google SignIn (Not with Firebase, it's done with OAuth 2.0 on Google Cloud)
2. Firestore (From the firebase stack only Firestore is used)

My question is will both of these services work on Huawei phones which is without GMS? As I don't think any of these are related to GMS and I Understand that some services like Push notifications if implemented from firebase will not work etc, but at the moment I'm only interested in these two services.

If not then, I'm using react native so is there a way to check if the user is from a Huawei phone that doesn't have GMS?

Comment: Have you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanTareq Huawei devices do not have access to Google Play Services, which is required to use the Firebase SDK. So there are two ways to get the above results... one is to use Huawei Mobile Services (HMS) OR as an alternate there is always Firebase REST API which you use to build your own BE that calls the firebase services and then call that API.

Comment: it's a good idea to use rest apis but I think I have read that firestore db works on Huawei devices do you have any idea?

Comment: Can't say for sure as it's been a while but this might be of help: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services#google_play_services_not_required taken from one of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340683/firebase-remote-config-realtime-database-on-huawei-devices

Answer (score 0):

Your app can be released to Huawei AppGallery normally.

> My question is will both of these services work on Huawei phones which is without GMS? As I don't think any of these are related to GMS and I Understand that some services like Push notifications if implemented from firebase will not work etc, but at the moment I'm only interested in these two services.

Huawei do provide an Android Virtual Device called [Cloud Debugging of AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-introduction) to test your app for Huawei Devices.You can run your app on the latest and most popular Huawei devices to test app functions.

For details, you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63877454/13329100).

Comment: Good resource about how to test for Huawei devices, but it doesn't fully answer OP's question though. I am facing a problem with Firebase Auth and Firebase Firestore when the app is run on Huawei devices. Anyone know how to workaround this significant problem, without breaking the code, which works perfectly on other Android and iOS devices?